# Foreign Key Causes WCF Socket Connection to Abort

Tags: c#, wcf, sockets, linq-to-sql

I have 2 tables, Unit and SubUnit, with a one to many relationship: a Unit can have 0 or more SubUnits.

I use Linq to SQL (.dbml files) in a WCF Windows Service to access the database.

Using the Service Client, I call any method to retrieve either the Units or the SubUnits and it works fine...as long as there are no SubUnits in the database (0 rows in the SubUnit table).

If there is 1 or more SubUnits, I get the following errors when calling the same methods:

- **"The socket connection was aborted..."**
- with inner exception "The read operation failed, see inner
  exception."
- with inner exception "The socket connection was
  aborted..."
- with inner exception **"An existing connection was forcibly
  closed by the remote host"**

I've dropped the tables and re-created them, I've re-added the Unit/SubUnit tables to the DBML, re-installed the service, etc. I've never run into this problem before.

I understand the "Socket aborted" error can be caused by trying to pass too much data over WCF, but there is currently 1 Unit with 1 SubUnit in the database and I still get this error!

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: you need to isolate what is the causing the issue first. change your WCF service so it returns a blank `Unit` (so it doesnt touch the database) then see if you still get the error -if so this would indicate a wcf/serialization issue. if that works, then you've likely some sort of db issue.

Comment: It's definitely a serialization issue. What's the best work around?

Comment: I think a part of the problem is it's a circular reference in a way: the SubUnit always has a Unit and the Unit always has a list of SubUnits.

Comment: are you running this from within Visual Studio? are you breaking on thrown Exceptions? (`Debug -> Exceptions... -> CLR Exceptions` (tick Thrown)
Also, try using the `BinaryFormatter` to serialize your data (in isolation to the WCF, perhaps in a unit test) so you can quickly determine if that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [DataContract(IsReference = true)] attr. to your entity.

Answer (score -1):

Had the exact same error/issue using a wcf client once I introduced Foreign key(s) on the db while using the Entity Framework in the wcf service.

The server-side calls and business logic to the entity framework worked just fine w/ the FK's, but client bombed when connecting to the service (returning a List).

I'm using the .edmx and also the EF 5.x DBContext Generator.

I had to Turning off lazy loading for all navigation properties.

i.e. in my model template, remove the ' virtual' keyword in the template:

```
public string AccessibilityAndVirtual(string accessibility)
    {
        return accessibility + (accessibility != "private" ? " virtual" : "");
    }
```

see [awesome post!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232#eagerLevels)

Comment: Now you broke the template, as you can never use lazy loading on entities generated with it again. Even though the template is only for that context, you should just disable lazy loading on the context as is mentioned the paragraph below the one you link to, because the latter is, as it is titled, for _"Turning off lazy loading for **specific** navigation properties"_.

Comment: If you're sure though that you don't want any generated entity's properties to be `virtual`, then please feel free to ask a question about this and self-answer it. Be sure though to explicitly mention in your question _why_ you need this, as disabling lazy loading on the context by setting the appropriate properties (`LazyLoadingEnabled` and perhaps `ProxyCreationEnabled`) to `false` is the recommended way to do this.

Comment: OK - was not really concerned about the LazyLoading on the entire context at this point, but went back and set it to True and all appears to work alright w/ just Turning off lazy loading for specific navigation properties

Comment: It appears to work because none of your entities have `virtual` properties, so none of those properties will be lazy-loaded, causing the circular reference exception to stay away.